# What is a circuit I could use to generate valid analog TV signal?

Tags: circuit-design, video, tv

What is the simplest valid analog TV signal and what circuit is required to generate it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139209/discussion-on-question-by-john-palermo-what-is-the-simplest-valid-composite-vide).

Comment: Depends on which country you are in, color vs. black-and-white, etc.  A sync generator chip makes all of the pulses necessary to form a monochrome black signal.  What is this for?

Comment: @AnalogKid I believe it's black&white since it's the simplest. Do different TVs have different sync requirements? I was under the impression that (apart from colour) they were reasonably flexible to adapt to different signal timing.

Comment: @AnalogKid I can answer that in chat as this conversation has been moved to chat.

Comment: I wanted to hazard an answer but not without actually trying it, and that's too much work. Because I found several sources for the overall format of the signal but not the specifics, here's an official reference with the specifics: https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.1700-0-200502-I/en - probably not useful for John but may be useful for whoever answers

Comment: Seems like the sort of thing that would be possible with an FPGA and a few resistors. [<click click>](https://github.com/infiniteNOP/ntsc_gen)

Comment: Some good suggestions mentioned in chat, but should be archived out here in the comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7rce6IQDWs ||| https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mega163_3_04.pdf  .My opinion is to watch the video, and then get yourself a [Basys3 FPGA board from Digilent](https://digilent.com/shop/).  It has a VGA port, so you can implement the hard logic in an FPGA.  Then once you nail that, you can attach your own RCA connector and circuit to the extra I/O on the board and make the necessary changes to implement a black&white NTSC video signal in 240p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial** answer (needing lots of improvement!) because nobody else has answered:

The behaviour of a TV is to make a beam of electrons, and steer, or *scan*, it from left-to-right, then back to the left and a little bit lower down, and so on. When it gets to the bottom right, then it goes to the top left and starts all over.

[image: CRT raster scan pattern]

A black-and-white, analog TV signal is *basically* just controlling the brightness of the beam. The voltage goes low when the beam is pointing at a black part of the image (turning the beam off), and high when the beam is pointing at a white part of the image (turning the beam to full brightness and making the screen light up) and of course in-between voltages make shades of grey.

*Some* TVs will let you just connect a varying voltage (or even a constant voltage) to the video pin, and get some drawing on the screen (but nothing predictable, more like TV static). Other TVs will display "no signal" instead. May as well try it.

The second function of the video signal is to sync up the TV's scan pattern with the "camera"'s (or game console's) scan pattern. You need these to be synced up or else the picture will be shifted off to the side, top or bottom of the screen. So at the end of each line, the console needs to output a horizontal sync pulse. At the end of the frame (when the TV is going back to the top) the console needs to output a vertical sync pulse. *(More info needed here about what these pulses actually look like)*. The TV scans using horizontal and vertical oscillators that try to lock onto the frequency of these pulses, and then the picture stays in the right place on the screen. If your TV displays "no signal" then having valid sync pulses should cause it to stop displaying "no signal".

To display a dot in the middle of the screen you need to get the sync pulses right, and then you can measure where the middle of the screen is, and make the voltage go high at that moment. To make a dot somewhere else you need to make it go high at a different moment. To draw a horizontal line leave it high for some time; to make a vertical line bring it high at the same time on each line. To make a diagonal line you would probably need an actual CPU to calculate the dot position on each line.

[AFAIK](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/sending-a-video-signal-through-an-rca-cable.137928/), 1.0V is full white, 0.0V is black, and -0.4V is used for synchronization pulses. I expect there is a reasonable amount of tolerance there and the TV will automatically adjust to it - after all, it is designed to receive radio signals with varying amplitude depending on how far away you are from the transmitter.

Comment: 0.714V is full white and -0.286V is sync for NTSC-M.  I think you are confusing the info from the link you reference.  They discuss IRE units which is mainly used in NTSC-M and each unit is equivalent to 7.14mV.  NTSC-J, which is much simpler to use, has 0.700V for white and 0.300V for sync.  Both systems result in a 1.0Vpp signal, which is the key takeaway.

Comment: @SteKulov if you are familiar with the system, please write your own answer!